# why my sessiosn are not working in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-cookies

I am using codeigniter-3 for developing the web part, i am using sessions for maintaining the user data once the user login if i click on any page or button the page is redirect to the login page.

i have two projects of codeigniter-3 if i launch the project-1 in browser and login with credentials it's navigating to the another page it's working fine,but in project-2 it's not working but same session configurations of both project-1 and project-2.

i am facing one  strange scenario if user is  login in project-1 and at a same time if user has login in project-2 in same browser the page redirections are working fine in project-2 .i tried with many solutions over the google nothing works for me can you please help me to fix this issue..?

**Expectation**

```
The page should navigate one page to another page instead of redirecting to login page
```

`congig.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
// $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

`LoginController.php`

```
$userdata = array(
                        'id'    =>$response_arr['data']['id'],
                        'user_id'  => $response_arr['data']['user_id'],
                        'role'      => $response_arr['data']['user_id'],
                );
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve your issue we have to dive in to the project,anyway I was thinking in your project  might be some checks like is_logged_in or user_logged_in as true because of this the page is return back to the login screen.

You have to add one more key value pair in $userdata array.before that you must have to verify in other
page controllers which check they add according to that you have to add key value pair like the following

```
$userdata=[is_logged_in =>TRUE];
```

Please let me know if this resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer i missed a check 'log_in' => TRUE